# A hyperlink which is directing to a section of different page is directing somewhere else on that page

Tags: html, css

I have a particular page called 'home page' in which there are several sections. when i open different page there are links getting back to different sections of the home page for example when i open page 'xyz' there are links for home, services, contact etc. But when i click services it redirects me to home page similarly when i click contact it redirects me to services section.etc

```
</li>
                                        <li> <a href="http://example/index.html#about">Locate Us</a></li>


                                        <!-- eof pages -->
                                        <li> <a href="http://example/index.html#pipeline">Features</a></li>


                                        <!-- Features -->
                                        <li> <a href="http://example/index.html#features">About</a>

                                        <!-- Testimonials -->
                                        <li> <a href="http://example/index.html#testimonial">Testimonials</a>
                                        </li>
```

When i click contact it should redirect me to contact section of home (index) page

Comment: First of all, do not use the whole url. Just the directory you wanna go to. It's irrelevant, it's supposed to be anchors, not redirects.

Comment: Do your page load content with a delay (or asynchronously if you know what it means), for example images or whole sections? That could explain why you land at the wrong place

Comment: @M4FI4S can you tell me with an example

Comment: no not any delays @Kaddath

Comment: I can't seee how your code explains your example

Comment: @liakoyras my sections ids are different dont mind that feature one was named ' 'about'. Please ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

Did u associate the `<section></section>` within your home page with a unique ID which you would want to redirect to?

Comment: Try something like ```<a href="test1">test1</a> and <section id="test1"></section>```

Comment: yes each section was given ids. within the home page when i click on nav bar it is directing exactly where it should go i used #example for that. But when i try to do it from different page it is directing to randomly somewhere on the page

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use [relative URLs](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp) as they have many advantages over absolute URLs.
For a file in the same folder, you can just use

```
<a href="filename.html">Testimonials</a>
```

while for a file inside a folder

```
<a href="path/filename.html">Testimonials</a>
```

If the file is in a higher folder than this of the referring file,

```
<a href="../filename.html">Testimonials</a>
```

(the `..` means one directory up)
If you want to go to a specific section, the same apply but you will need to add the id

```
<a href="filename.html#section_id">Testimonials</a>
```

This supposes that inside `filename.html`, there is a `section` tag with this id

```
<section id="section_id">
    <!-- HTML CODE -->
</section>
```

If the section is on the same page, use just the id:

```
<a href="#section_id">Testimonials</a>
```

If it still doesn't work, maybe its an issue of your content's size.